# how to break from a loop in node.js?

Tags: node.js, loops, express

I wrote this code in node.js to verify username and password from a json of users. problem is it keeps looping through all the users although a valid user is already found. How do I break the loop when a valid user is found?

```
users.forEach(function (user) {
          if(req.body.username==user.username){
              if(req.body.password==user.password){
                    console.log('validate success');
                    res.status(200).send({message:'user validation successful'});
              }
          }
          else{
               console.log('validate failed');
               res.status(404).send({message:'user validation failed'});
          }
});
```

Comment: You should probably use [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to do what you're wanting to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the user matching the username and if you find one, check the password. This way, you can also provide the right error message to tell the user what's wrong (username or password)

```
const user = users.find(function (user) {
  return user.username === req.body.username
})

if (!user) {
  return res.status(404).send({ message: 'User not found' })
}

if (user.password !== req.body.password) {
  return res.status(404).send({ message: 'Wrong pasword' })
}

// everything is alright
return res.status(200).send({message:'user validation successful'})
```

You can use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to make the find shorter

```
const user = users.find(u => (u.username === req.body.username))
```

Comment: You have  linked to the french doc, be careful :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong function. You use **`forEach`** if you want to loop over **all** the entries. If you need to find a **subset**, you use **`filter`**, and if you need **only one** result, you use **`find`** : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

So your code, with some other improvements, will become :

```
const loggedUser = users.find((user) => {
    return req.body.username === user.username && req.body.password === user.password
})
```

I know I could have shorten this even more, but it is clearer as it is right now IMO.